# What is the correct syntax to check if a user has permission?

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce

In my plugin, I am checking to see if the current logged in user has permission to save a commerce product.

```
$user = craft()->userSession->getUser();
if (craft()->userPermissions->doesUserHavePermission($user->id, 'ManageClothingProducts')) {
    // yes permission
} else {
  // no permission
};
```

However, it seems I'm always getting into the `else`.

The commerce docs mention this:

> Manage [type] products

Maybe I'm not using the correct syntax? I'm only using the clothing products as an example. Ultimately I'll be checking for my own products.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct permission key is:

`commerce-manageProductType:ID_OF_PRODUCT_TYPE_HERE`

for example:

`commerce-manageProductType:2`

Your code would therefore be:

```php
$user = craft()->userSession->getUser();
if (craft()->userPermissions->doesUserHavePermission($user->id, 'commerce-manageProductType:2')) {
    // yes permission
} else {
  // no permission
};
```

Or you could use [UserSessionService::checkPermission()](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/UserSessionService#checkPermission-detail), which is a shortcut for checking permissions for the currently logged-in user:

```php
if (craft()->userSession->checkPermission('commerce-manageProductType:2')
```

Comment: Thanks Luke & Brandon! It's interesting though, when I am logged in as the site admin, this works: `craft()->userSession->checkPermission('commerce-manageProductType:1')`. However, this says I do not have permission `craft()->userPermissions->doesUserHavePermission($user->id, 'commerce-manageProductType:1')`